# Custom layout for portlet containers

Tags: html, css, websphere-portal

I'm creating a custom `layout` for a `WebSphere Portal` theme.
I'd like to have 2 rows, each row having 2 `portlet` containers beside eachother, each occupying 50% of screen width.
When portlets are added to the containers I'd like them to follow a column order.
Anyone any experience with layouts in `websphere portal`?

```
<div class="hiddenWidgetsDiv">
    <!-- widgets in this container are hidden in the UI by default -->
    <div class="component-container hiddenWidgetsContainer ibmDndRow wpthemeCol12of12 wpthemeFull" name="ibmHiddenWidgets"></div>
    <div style="clear:both"></div>
</div>

<div class="wpthemeRow">
    <div>
        <div class="component-container wpthemeCol ibmDndColumn wpthemeCol6of12" name="headline1"></div>
    </div>

    <div>
        <div class="component-container wpthemeCol ibmDndColumn wpthemeCol6of12" name="headline2"></div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="wpthemeRow">
    <div>
        <div class="component-container wpthemeCol ibmDndColumn wpthemeCol6of12" name="headline3"></div>
    </div>

    <div>
        <div class="component-container wpthemeCol ibmDndColumn wpthemeCol6of12" name="headline4"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

But markup results in this layout, which looks very odd ..

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I went for in the end ..

```
<style>
.container {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding-top: 35px;
    position: relative;
}

 .gridBlock, .gridBlock2 {
    width: 49%;
    height: 200px;
    padding: 0px;
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.gridBlock {
    margin: 2px;
}
.gridBlock2 {
    margin: 3px, 0;
    float: right;
}
</style>

<div class="hiddenWidgetsDiv">
    <!-- widgets in this container are hidden in the UI by default -->
    <div class="component-container hiddenWidgetsContainer ibmDndRow wpthemeCol12of12 wpthemeFull" name="ibmHiddenWidgets"></div>
    <div style="clear:both"></div>
</div>



<div class="component-container wpthemeRow ibmDndRow" name="headline"></div>

<div class="container">
    <div class="component-container wpthemeCol ibmDndColumn gridBlock" name="secondary"></div>
    <div class="component-container wpthemeCol ibmDndColumn gridBlock2" name="ibmMainContainer"></div>

    <div class="component-container wpthemeCol ibmDndColumn gridBlock" name="secondary2"></div>
    <div class="component-container wpthemeCol ibmDndColumn gridBlock2" name="ibmMainContainer2"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Are you trying to create 2 rows with 2 columns? I feel like you're struggling and unsatisfied with the fact that you're using 49% instead of 50%.

Comment: @bigal yes, aiming for a 2x2 grid basically. When I used `50%` I was getting wrapping issues

Comment: Perhaps try looking in to using the css box-sizing: border-box? (If you can recreate this in a jsfiddle, it would help me a lot)